# Get random operators and integers

Tags: java, random

im doing an assignment which requires me to create 3 classes.

- 1 with getting 2 random integers,
- 1 with getting random operators such as + - * / which should be done so in char method
- the last one to check if the simple mathematics answer is correct using booleans via user Scanner input.

i need a little help here as im not sure if i've done the random operators method correctly and am really lost at how i should tabulate both random int and operators together in one class.

here's the code i've done so far:

```
    public static char getOperator (int x, int y)
    {
        char operator;
        int answer;
        
        switch (rand.nextInt(4))
          {
            case 0: operator = '+';
                    answer = x + y;
                    break;
                    
            case 1: operator = '-';
                    answer = x - y;;
                    break;
                    
            case 2: operator = '*';
                    answer = x * y;;
                    break;
                    
            case 3: operator = '/';
                    answer = x / y;;
                    break;
                    
            default: operator = '?';
          }
        return operator;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you mean you need to create 3 **methods** (and not classes).

1. One that creates a random integer (it's a bad design to create a
   method that returns two integers instead of just calling two times
   one that returns one int).
2. One that returns a random operator
3. One that checks if an operation consisting of "*random-number
   random-operator random-number*" is equal to user input

Anyways, there's a lot to unpack here, so:

Your first method **getTwoIntegers** is incorrect, you're asking for two integers in input but you never actually use them, then you return one random number.

The method **getOperator** needs to be redesigned to have no input and return one char (equal to + - x /).

Your final method will call the your first method twice, then the second method once, it will then print the operation for the user to see, and check if the response is correct.

Hopefully this can help you conceptualize better the way you should build your code.
I didn't post the source code since I believe it's much better for you if you try to do it by yourself (this being an assignment and all)

Good luck and have fun :)